# How to view the whole KML

Tags: google-maps, kml

When I load a KML in Google maps, it doesn't show all polygons, instead there are Google "next-previous" pages, each containing parts of the KML. How can I view all the information in one page?

Comment: Could you please upload  your kml file ? OR Please copy and paste your shape file (http://display-kml.appspot.com/) OR check out following link http://support.google.com/mapsengine/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2505884 AND if possible please upload the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

There are limits everywhere.

I guess it's just that. When you have more features, they are just simply split into different pages.

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on
>   a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, none of your layers
>   will display. The limit is based on the total length of all URLs
>   passed to the KMLLayer class, and consequently will vary by
>   application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20
>   layers without hitting the limit.

[*From Google KML Support*](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)